# Use private variable of a class in its member function

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I am using EditText field as below, I got the error that android your app has stopped with console error *"channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed"*

```
public class SignupActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        Intent resign = getIntent();
    }

    public void signUp() {
        String tname = name.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

It worked fine when I change the class as,

```
public class SignupActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        Intent resign = getIntent();
    }

    public void signUp() {
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        String tname = name.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Why it is not working when I use the above code, please help, thanks  advance

Comment: Why have you commented out half the code in each case? Is it important or not? Where are you calling the `SignUpActivity` constructor? What does the stack trace look like? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: It is solved thanks, commented portion is not useful please neglect it

Comment: Then please delete the irrelevant part. Read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `findViewById()` too early, before `onCreate()`. It will NPE because there's no `Window` yet to find the view in.

Generally, you shouldn't be calling any activity method before `onCreate()`.

Correct place for `findViewById()` is `onCreate()` or later so that there's a `Window`, and after `setContentView()` so that something can actually be found.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code:

```
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
        Intent resign = getIntent();
    }
```

What You Should Do:

```
public class SignupActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);

        Intent resign = getIntent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand one thing, widgets which you have declared in your XML file associated with your activity are not available to you until OnCreate is called

```
"setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup)" , you are trying to make it as member variable which will try to get them initialize even before onCreate is called, and hence the error.
```

Comment: Incorrect. They only get inflated when setContentView is called, even when that's in something like onResume

Comment: read my full answers, I have mentioned "setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup)", please dont put comments without reading it properly this might misguide others.

Comment: "widgets which you have declared in your XML file associated with your activity are not available to you until OnCreate is called". That is an incorrect statement. Yes, you do mention `setContentVeiw`, but you don't explain it. You do not link the error and setContentView, you merely mention both in one sentence, but that sentence lacks internal correlation.

Answer (score 1):

here you are initializing Edit text before  calling  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);`
method

Answer (score 1):

Move this

```
  EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
```

after

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
```